# Store value on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to store a text value of a html form when click the submit button on a variable. The value gets stored just a second right away when the submit button is clicked and then goes blanck again. Why is this happening?

```js
var userSearch = "";

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#buttonA").click(function() {
    userSearch = document.getElementById("userSearch").value;
    console.log(userSearch);

  });
  console.log(userSearch);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ca5f7b6f9a.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container text-center">
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"> Random article</a>
    <div id="searchBox">
      <form>
        <input type="text" id="userSearch" name="userSearch">
        <button id="buttonA">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="resultsBox"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You are submitting form by click and page reloads

Comment: When you click submit the entire page is being reloaded thus loosing the previous values. If you need to keep the value then look at cookies or localstorage objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pressing a button inside a `form` submits the form by default. Therefore your page is reloaded and you lose any state of the client side variables.

To prevent this you could:

- prevent for submission by calling `e.preventDefault()` on the event object passed in the listener
- use another mechanism (ex. cookies) to pass the variable from one page load to the other

## Example `preventDefault`

```js
var userSearch = "";

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#buttonA").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    userSearch = document.getElementById("userSearch").value;
    console.log(userSearch);

  });
  console.log(userSearch);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/ca5f7b6f9a.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container text-center">
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random"> Random article</a>
    <div id="searchBox">
      <form>
        <input type="text" id="userSearch" name="userSearch">
        <button id="buttonA" type="button">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div id="resultsBox"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are clicking submit, by nature (of the button), the page reloads. This resets the existing form values. Ideally, you'd take your users to a new page that'll be served by a server side language such as PHP. If you want your data to stay the way you entered, change the `<button id="buttonA">Submit</button>` to `<input type="button" value="submit">`.

Alternatively, use cookies to store the form values between page reloads.

Note however, your existing script runs fine in the snippet. So there might be something else going wrong on your machine(at your end).